# How exactly does the +1 airjump mechanic work?

Tags: dustforce

When defeating an enemy in mid-air, your character is able to use his/her jump again once more while in the air.
I understand that from the tutorial.

But now, let's take for example the blue character, he can jump once and then again while in mid-air. If he jumps, then defeats two enemies, how many more times will he be able to use his jump ability before he lands? Just once? Or twice or three times?

Also, if our blue character jumps, defeats an enemy and then uses his doublejump (*in mid-air*) and then defeats another enemy(*still in mid-air*), how many more 'jumps' does he have left?

And how does this work with the purple character, who can jump and then do two more jumps while in air?

Sorry for the maybe a little confusing wording of the question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Defeating an enemy mid-jump replenishes **all** of your character's air-jumps.  For the blue, red, and green characters, this means one air-jump.  For the purple character, it's two.

You can never have more than the character's specific air-jump count stored up, so it doesn't matter how many enemies you defeat in a single jump.  You'll still end up with that character's default amount, now replenished (This means you can defeat one enemy to get two air-jumps with the purple character).

---

**Air-Jumps, by character:**

- Blue: One
- Red: One
- Purple: Two
- Green: One